# How to convert 'for each' loop to a Java 8 'Stream'

Tags: java, java-stream

how to convert an iteration loop 'to' to the stream o java 8 Include a method in your body that searches for results?

```
for(VagasRemanecentesResponse  turaluAUnic : turaluListaA){
       listAlunoCursoResponse = alunoCursoBusiness.findByCodInstAndRgmAlun(inst, turaluAUnic.getRgmAluno());
       if (listAlunoCursoResponse.size() > 0) {
          aluCurListaB.add(new VagasRemanecentesResponse(turaluAUnic, listAlunoCursoResponse));
       }
      }
```

or a simpler example that represents part of the problem, like not using 'for'

```
for(Student student: students ) {
      listAlunoCursoResponse.addAll(findByid(student.getId));
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly possible, your code is certain to be clearer the way it current is.  A stream-based version would need to keep track of both the `turaluAUnic` element and the corresponding `listAlunoCursoResponse`.

Comment: I checked examples of how the map and flow work, but I didn't find an option that I have a method call within the iteration loop. How can this be done ? In a simple example for example I have a list of student identifiers and make several calls to a method where I pass a student's identifier to obtain the filled object.

Comment: It would be something like this: students.foreach(student -> listAlunoCursoResponse.addAll(findByid(student.getId))) but as a VGR said its pointless..

Comment: @miljon just to compare the stream version for the latter code would look like `List<AlunoCurso> list =  students.stream().flatMap(student -> findByid(student.getId).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `findByid` returns an `Object` instead of a `Collection` (otherwise you have to use `flatMap`):

```
listAlunoCursoResponse.addAll(students.stream()
                .map(student -> findByid(student.getId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```